# DropDownListFor selection not working -- again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

Yeah, I know, this question's been asked/answered 34798796873.5 times. I looked through all 3 bajillion of them, and I still have the problem. What am I missing here?

I tried several approaches and none of them work. Here are my latest attempts:

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Author",
    Model.AuthorItems.Select(i =>
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = i.Id == Model.Author.Id
        }), "無し")%>

<%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Author,
    new SelectList(Model.AuthorItems,
        "Id",
        "Name",
        Model.Author),
    "無し") %>
```

My view model is very straightforward:

```
public class EditArticleViewModel
{
    public AuthorItem Author { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthorItem> AuthorItems { get; set; }
    public class AuthorItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I made sure my action is working correctly; sure enough, Author has an Id of 5, and AuthorItems has an entry whose Id is 5.

I even tried overriding Equals and GetHashCode in the model.

Blahhhhh!!1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your view model replace:

```
public AuthorItem Author { get; set; }
```

with

```
public int? SelectedAuthorId { get; set; }
```

and in your view bind the dropdown list to this `SelectedAuthorId`:

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.SelectedAuthorId,
    new SelectList(Model.AuthorItems, "Id", "Name"),
    "無し"
) %>
```

Now as long as you provide a valid `SelectedAuthorId` value in your controller action:

```
model.SelectedAuthorId = 123;
```

The HTML helper that renders the dropdown will correctly preselect the item from the list that has this given id.

The reason for this is that in a dropdown list you can select only a single value (a scalar type) and not an entire Author (all that is sent in the HTTP request when you submit the form is this selected value).

Comment: Well that was fast. No idea why that works and none of the other approaches do, but thanks!

Comment: What other approaches? You cannot bind a dropdown list to a complex object (Author in your case) which is what you were trying to do. If you want to get the corresponding author back in your POST action use the provided id to fetch it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList/DropDownListFor used ModelState value. So set ViewDataDictionary selectedValue in controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new EditArticleViewModel
          {
            Author = new EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem() {Id = 3, Name = "CCC"},
            AuthorItems = new List<EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem>()
            {
              new EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem() {Id = 1, Name = "AAA"},
              new EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem() {Id = 2, Name = "BBB"},
              new EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem() {Id = 3, Name = "CCC"},
              new EditArticleViewModel.AuthorItem() {Id = 4, Name = "DDD"},
            }
          };

  ViewData["Author"] = model.Author.Id;
  return View(model);
}
```

View code simple.

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Author", 
        new SelectList(Model.AuthorItems,
            "Id",
            "Name"), "無し")%>

<%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Author,
    new SelectList(Model.AuthorItems,
        "Id",
        "Name"),
    "無し")%>
```

ViewData key "Author" is using model state binding for selected value.

Hope this help.